# Quartz triggers are firing ahead of time

Tags: triggers, quartz-scheduler

We are using quartz 2.1.5, on 64 bit machine (clustered, 2 instances, 16GB ram). We have around 8000 triggers in the system.

Every second we have around 50 triggers - they get fired every second.

```
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 50
org.quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount=100
org.quartz.scheduler.idleWaitTime=15000
#org.quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionFireAheadTimeWindow=0 (this is not set)
```

Quartz is able to handle the load, but triggers get fired ahead of time?

batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount - can we increase it to 500 and keep batchTriggerAcquisitionFireAheadTimeWindow at 1000 (1 sec), is there any disadvantage of these configuration?

Any other way?

with following configuration, it seems to work fine.

```
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 100
org.quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount=500
org.quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionFireAheadTimeWindow=1000
org.quartz.scheduler.idleWaitTime=25000
```

Answer (score 2):

When quartz wants to run your triggers it calls this method :

```
triggers = qsRsrcs.getJobStore().acquireNextTriggers(now + idleWaitTime, Math.min(availThreadCount, qsRsrcs.getMaxBatchSize()), qsRsrcs.getBatchTimeWindow());
```

Where :

- `idleWaitTime` is `org.quartz.scheduler.idleWaitTime`
- `availThreadCount` is the number of free threads (will be less or equal to `org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount`)
- `qsRsrcs.getMaxBatchSize()` is `org.quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount`
- `qsRsrcs.getBatchTimeWindow()` is `org.quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionFireAheadTimeWindow`

it leads to an SQL request like :

```
SELECT * FROM TRIGGERS WHERE NEXT_FIRE_TIME <= now + idleWaitTime + qsRsrcs.getBatchTimeWindow() LIMIT Math.min(availThreadCount, qsRsrcs.getMaxBatchSize())
```

So yes, Quartz always runs triggers ahead of time with `idleWaitTime + qsRsrcs.getBatchTimeWindow()`. The minimum number of triggers that it takes will be if you set getBatchTimeWindow to zero, and idleWaitTime to 1000 (it's a minimal value). In this case it will still take triggers that are supposed to happen 1 second ahead of time in addition to those, which are expected to run.

If you want to stop taking triggers ahead of time completely you can set `batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount` to 1. The downside in this case is that you can get too many SQL requests. You can try to play with `batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount` parameter and find the value that suits you best.

BTW Looking on the Quartz code you can see that setting batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount bigger than threadCount makes no sense.

Comment: does it mean, because of idleWaitTime - they would anyways be fired ahead of time? or quartz get them in-memory ahead of time, and fires them as per the scheduled time?

Comment: Yes, they will always run ahead of time due to idleWaitTime. Quartz fires them almost immediately after getting (it adds the corresonding jobs as tasks to the thread pool). So the accuracy is determined by idleWaitTime. I would guess that quartz is not intended for exact real-time planning.

Comment: Also it won't run triggers ahead of time if you set batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount = 1, or threadCount = 1.

Comment: batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount=1, was not working for such a load, we had to enable batch to support. we are talking about 50-100 triggers per second.

Comment: This behaviour (taking triggers ahead of time) looks like a bug to me. You can actually see that there's a strange variable "firstAcquiredTriggerFireTime" in JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger that is initialized, but not used. I see that in the quartz .NET port it's actually used for the check that blocks running triggers ahead of time. You can probably report this on quartz forums so that they investigate this issue. RAMJobStore also has this unused variable. You might want to try the older version of quartz where this check still exists.

Comment: org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 200 
org.quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount=200
org.quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionFireAheadTimeWindow=1000org.quartz.scheduler.idleWaitTime=20000  The problem is less severe, its breaking again but after 25000 triggers, earlier it was breaking at 8000 triggers.